# Python plistlib to read plist Typeerror

Tags: python, plist, typeerror, startswith

I am trying to read plist files from an iPhone using plistlib. The error I keep getting is:

"builtins.TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes"

I have tried the following code:

```
f = open('C:/testing/MadMaxInfo.plist','r', encoding='UTF-8')
plist = plistlib.readPlist(f)
print(plist)
```

-and-

```
with open('C:/testing/MadMaxInfo.plist','r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    plist = plistlib.readPlist(f)
    print(plist)
```

Both give me that same error. I have also used plistlib.load() as it seems to be the more current function. Same error/output.

If I run:

```
with open('C:/testing/MadMaxInfo.plist','r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:  
    for lines in f:
        line = f.readline()
        print(line)
```

That will print out the plist just fine, but obviously not in a format I can manipulate the data in. I am not sure why I am getting that specific error, as plistlib is looking for xml at the beginning of the file, and that is what is at the beginning of the file. Thanks.

Comment: What version of python? Does it work without `encoding='UTF-8'`?

Comment: Python version 3.5.2

Comment: When I remove the encoding it gives me the same error. (no change in function)

Comment: Apparently the issue is a 3.5 issue. I opened up a command prompt and just ran some test code using 2.7 and it worked just fine. :( ... well at least I solved the issue.

Comment: Sounds like plistlib might need to be updated. Might be worth filing a bug against it.